# What's the meaning of "should not have been"?

Tags: meaning, tense

> Arguably, the drug **should not have been** made available.

What's the meaning of this sentence? Could you paraphrase it? Why *should* is added?

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is in the passive voice. That may be what is confusing you.

"Should not" here tells you that this is the author's opinion. The author thinks it was a bad idea.

"Have been" is the progressive/continuous tense.

"Been" is "to be", the verb used in passive voice constructions.

Here are some paraphrases:

> The drug was made available by pharmaceutical companies, but it should
> not have been because...
>
> Pharmaceutical companies decided to make this drug available (to the
> public), but this was a bad decision because...